# How to use set_intersection and insert into a set

Tags: c++, c++11, graph, set, intersection

I'm trying to build a class of a graph, which is represented by edges and vertices.

I have implemented the edges as a string set, and the vertices as a string set, and would like to create methods in order to create intersections and unions between my created graphs.
This is the class:

```
class Graph {
public:
    string name;
    std::set<string> vertices;
    std::set<string> edges; //<v1,v2> format
    Graph()= default;
    Graph(const Graph&) = default;
    ~Graph() = default;
    Graph graphUnion(const Graph& graph);
    Graph graphIntersection(const Graph& graph);
};
```

I used the std::set_intersection function for my method:

```
Graph Graph::graphIntersection(const Graph& graph){
    Graph new_graph;
    std::set<string> new_vertices;
    new_vertices.end() = std::set_intersection(this->vertices.begin(), this->vertices.end(), graph.vertices.begin(),
            graph.vertices.end(), new_vertices.begin());
    std::set<string> new_edges;
    new_edges.end() = std::set_intersection(this->edges.begin(), this->edges.end(), graph.edges.begin(),
                                            graph.edges.end(), new_edges.begin());

    new_graph.vertices = new_vertices;
    new_graph.edges = new_edges;

    return new_graph;
}
```

Yet when I try to run it I get the following error, which has something to do with the set_intersection function in `<algorithm>`

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:5415:27: error: no viable overloaded '='
                *__result = *__first1;
                ~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
```

Please help me identify this error since I can't tell what is the problem here...

Thank you!

Comment: Assigning to `.end()` is meaningless.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you! can you please explain why? since as I've understood the set_intersection function returns an Iterator to the end of the new set, no?

Answer (score 1):

You need a couple things:

```
/*new_edges.end() =*/
std::set_intersection(this->edges.begin(), this->edges.end(), 
    graph.edges.begin(), graph.edges.end(), 
         std::inserter(new_edges, new_edges.begin()));
```

No need to set the end. The container will manage that itself.

You need to have an inserter object that tells which set to add to, and at which position.

Answer (score 1):

`.end()`

> Returns an iterator referring to the *past-the-end* element in the
> container.

Therefore you can't assign to it (but you can compare to it). You probably want to do something like this:

```
std::set<string>::iterator it = std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
```

or

```
std::set<string> result;
std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                      v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                      std::inserter(result, result.begin()));
```